# pass data from MySQL to marquee text view in anther activity

Tags: java, android, json

I pass data from MySQL to  marquee text in activity one and It works successfully , but I need to send these text to anther activity by intent but not warking for me , Please help

activity One :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dollars);
    item_k001 = findViewById(R.id.item_k101);
    item_k002 = findViewById(R.id.item_k102);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    final Globalv globalv = (Globalv) getApplicationContext();
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("allegg");
                        String msg = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject respons = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            final String myItem_k001 = respons.getString("item_k1");
                            final String myItem_k002 = respons.getString("item_k2");
                            DollarsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    item_k001.setText(myItem_k001);
                                    item_k002.setText(myItem_k002);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        JSONObject respons2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        String id = respons2.getString("id");
                        globalv.setTotal_threads(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id)));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
        }
    }
    );
```

I want to send tow text to activity tow :

```js
        //defines variables to the xml elements.
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.marqueeTextView1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.marqueeTextView2);
        ///  You can change your text here
        tv1.setText("Text view");
        tv2.setText("Text view   ");
        // We set the setSelected value to true for the shift of the texts
        tv1.setSelected(true);
        tv2.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:

*Activity 1*

```
intent = new Intent(OneActivity.this, TwoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY1", myItem_k001);
intent.putExtra("KEY2", myItem_k002);
startActivity(intent);
```

*Activity 2*

```
//In onCreate()
Intent intent = getIntent();
text1 = intent.getStringExtra("KEY1");
text2 = intent.getStringExtra("KEY2")
tv1.setText(text1);
tv2.setText(text2);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to start activity 2 when you get the text, you can can use intent,
but if activity2 was opened later and it is onPouse now, 
you can easily use interface :

in sampleInterface:

```
public interface sampleInterface{
    void setText(String text);
}
```

in activity 1 add:

```
sampleInterface callBack;
```

in activity 1 put this into that line that you get your text:

```
callBack.setText("your Text");
```

in activity 2:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements  ,sampleInterface{

TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout_2);
        textView= findViewById(R.id.textView);

}

    @Override
    public void setText(String yourText) {
        textView.setText(yourText);
    }

}
```

where ever you call `callback.setText("your text here");` this will fire `@Override`
method in Ativity2 and it return your text

hope this be helpfull